# How to get value from select box in html table

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to retrieve a value from a select box in my HTML table. How can I select the selected value?

What I've tried so far:

```
this.cells[14].innerHTML; 
this.cells[14].children[0].innerhtml; 
this.cells[14].children[0].innerText; 

The last one .innerText returns all the items in my select box......
```

```
var table2 = document.getElementById('table_items_program');

        for (var i2 = 1; i2 < table2.rows.length; i2++) {
            table2.rows[i2].onclick = function () {
                document.getElementById("id").value = this.cells[0].innerHTML;
                document.getElementById("select").value = this.cells[14].children[0].innerText;
            }
        }
```

```
<td><select class="selectpicker" multiple>
<?php while ($row9 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result9)):; ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $row9['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row9['id'];?>                  
      </option> 
<?php endwhile; ?>                   
</select></td>

<input style="display: inline" id="id" name="id">
<input style="display: inline" id="select" name="select">
```

The selected value from my selection box in my HTML table

Comment: Have you tried `.value`?

Comment: @freefaller Yes I did, that returns undefined

Comment: Your are getting elements with the id "id" and "select" can you include the related html

Comment: @R3tep Sure! That are just 2 input fields where I can see what the javascript returns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I select the selected value?

You can get the selected index with the method [`HTMLSelect​Element​.selected​Index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex)

---

But if I understand your trouble. You try to get the current values of your select. So you need to get the value of your selected options.

You can do it like:

```js
document.getElementById('mySelect').onchange = function() {
  let options = this && this.options;
  let selectedValues = []
  for (var i = options.length; i--;) {
    let opt = options[i];
    if (opt.selected) {
      selectedValues.push(opt.value || opt.text);
    }
  }
  console.log(selectedValues)
}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect" multiple>
  <option value="a"> a </option>
  <option value="b"> b </option>
  <option value="c"> c </option>
</select>
```

---

Implementation into your code example

```js
for (var i2 = 1; i2 < table2.rows.length; i2++) {
  table2.rows[i2].onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("id").value = this.cells[0].innerHTML;

    var options = this && this.cells[14].children[0].options;
    var selectedValues = []
    for (var i = options.length; i--;) {
      var opt = options[i];
      if (opt.selected) {
        selectedValues.push(opt.value || opt.text);
      }
    }
    document.getElementById("select").value = JSON.stringify(selectedValues);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

So, your `<select>` has the class `selectpicker`. We can use this to select your `<select>`!

Try the following to get your value:

```js
document.querySelector(".selectpicker").value;
```

Or, if you have multiple `<select>`'s, you can use

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll(".selectpicker")].forEach(opt => {
   console.log(opt.value)
});
```

Hope that clears things up a little.

Comment: And how can I select the value from the selected row?

Answer (score 1):

so simple...

```js
ShowSelected.onclick = function()
{
  console.clear()
  document.querySelectorAll('.selectpicker option:checked').forEach(opt=>console.log(opt.value))
}
```

```css
.selectpicker { 
  vertical-align: text-top;
  }
```

```html
choose one or more :
<select class="selectpicker" multiple size=6 >
  <option value="a"> A element</option>
  <option value="b"> B element</option>
  <option value="c"> C element</option>
  <option value="d"> D element</option>
  <option value="e"> E element</option>
  <option value="f"> F element</option>

</select>
 
<button id="ShowSelected"> Show Selected</button>
```